# Is it possible to list s3 buckets by type i.e. Standard, Standard IA, Reduced Redundancy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to audit my buckets to see which buckets have what type of storage configuration. Is it possible to list s3 buckets by type with the aws cli i.e. Standard, Standard IA, Reduced Redundancy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to only list objects of a particular storage class:

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket my-bucket --query 'Contents[?StorageClass==`STANDARD_IA`].[Key]' --output text
```

Or, if you have a large quantity of objects, you might consider using [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a regular list of objects, including their Storage Class.

Comment: I guess I just have to loop over each bucket :/ . I was hoping I was able to just list all buckets of a certain storage class.

Comment: Each object has a Storage Class setting. Buckets do not have a Storage Class.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification.